# Approximation in $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, approximation-theory

I want to prove that if $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(R)$ then $f_n(X)\to f(X)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ for each random variable X. I think of using the dominated convergence theorem, having the puntual convergence, but how can I dominate this function? I would appreciate any idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $X$ be constant random variables, you want to say $f_n(x)$ converge to $f(x)$ pointwisely?

Comment: @LiuGang: no, in $L^2$, but if X is constant it's obvious.

Comment: Say $X=x$ constantly, then $E|f_n(X) - f(X)|^2 = |f_n(x) - f(x)|^2$, which does not necessarily converge to $0$ if we only know $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(R)$

Comment: @LiuGang: if you consider a subsequence it does.

Comment: @user62138 In your question you don't mention subsequences.

Comment: It does for almost every $x$, and it's only for a subsequence. So the result you want to prove is not true in general. You need more assumptions

Comment: @LiuGang:  so $f_{n_k}(X)\to f(X)$ almost everywhere. How can I deduce the $L^2$ convergence for this subsequence?

Comment: @user62138 Firstly, convergence almost everywhere doesn't imply convergence in $L^2$. Secondly, you don't have convergence everywhere if $X =x$ and $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$. In this case, you have convergence nowhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liu Gang already explained the various reasons why this does not work, but here is a concrete example: 
$$f_n(x) = \max(0,1-n|x|),\qquad f(x)\equiv 0; \qquad X\equiv 0$$
Here $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$. On the other hand, $f_n(X)$  does not converge to $f(X)$ in any sense, because $f_n(X)\equiv 1$ and $f(X)\equiv 0$.